# Limitar a un carácter la entrada del usuario

Tags: c++, matrices

Saludos.

Esta es la porción del código que necesito arreglar:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

char dato[4][4];

cout<<"Digite los datos de la matriz en cada posici\242n"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
      cout<<"Digite un numero para la posici\242n ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
      cin>>dato[i][j];
      //aquí iría la comprobación del dato[i][j]
    }
```

Vale. lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario este digitado los caracteres, limitar el numero de caracteres a 1 (algo así como un posible error -de no mas de un carácter) algo así:

```
if(long>=2){
cout<<"Solo se permite un solo carácter";
}
```

*long=longitud de los caracteres digitados.

Ahora el problema es que como es una matriz ([4][4]), no he podido sacar la longitud del/de los caracteres digitados y analizarlos con el if para ver si superan el largo de 1, y ya ahí sacar algún tipo de repetición o que se salga, etc.

he intentado utilizando el strlen(),sizeof(), copiando la primera posición(dato[0][0]) en otra variable y así analizarla; ninguno a funcionado ya no se que hacer.

ayuda -soy nuevo en esto así que :)-

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

> Quiero hacer [...] que cuando el usuario este digitado los caracteres, limitar el numero de caracteres a 1 (algo así como un posible error -de no mas de un carácter).

Yo leería la entrada del usuario al completo, y si es más larga de 1 carácter mostraría el error:

```
std::string linea;

while (std::getline(std::cin, linea) && linea.size() != 1)
{
    std::cout << "No mas de un caracter\n";
}
```

---

No incluyas `<conio.h>`, que además de ser una librería de C, no la estás usando.

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo donde estas pidiendo al usuario que ingrese un caracter y lo guardas en una variable, todo eso metelo en un ciclo `do-while` con la condicion `input.length() != 1`

Entonces el usuario estara obligado a ingresar el valor valido **(en tu caso 1 char)** para que el programa siga su flujo normal.

PD: `cin>>dato[i][j];`**No guardes el dato ingresado por el usuario directamente!** Guarda el dato en una variable `input`, validala y si pasa el cilo `do-while`, mete el contenido dentro de la matriz [f][c]

Comment: Sería aconsejable añadir código que mostrase lo que intentas explicar con palabras... así la respuesta sería más útil y, seguramente, mejor valorada